# Python: Adding a Dataframe column based on three other columns, two being filled with True/False

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is a mock dataframe of a much larger dataframe.
I have this:

| ID | Category | Shipped T/F? | Hold T/F? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | False | False |
| 456 | ABC | False | True |
| 789 | ABC | True | False |
| 234 | ABC | True | True |
| 567 | DEF | False | False |
| 678 | DEF | False | False |
| 135 | DEF | False | False |
| 246 | DEF | False | False |
| 369 | KGH | True | True |

I want this:

| ID | Category | Shipped T/F? | Hold T/F? | NewCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | False | False | 1 |
| 456 | ABC | False | True | 1 |
| 789 | ABC | True | False | 1 |
| 234 | ABC | True | True | 0 |
| 567 | DEF | False | False | 0 |
| 678 | DEF | False | False | 0 |
| 135 | DEF | False | False | 0 |
| 246 | DEF | False | False | 0 |
| 369 | KGH | True | True | 0 |

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=[
    ['123','ABC', False, False],
    ['456','ABC', False, True],
    ['789','ABC', True, False],
    ['234','ABC', True, True],
    ['567','DEF', False, False],
    ['678','DEF', False, True],
    ['135','DEF', True, False],
    ['246','DEF', True, True],
    ['369','KGH', True, True]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','Category','Shipped T/F?','Hold T/F?'])

Conditions = [
    (df['Category'] != 'ABC'),
    (df['Shipped T/F?'].bool==True and df['Hold T/F?'].bool==True)
    (df['Category'] == 'ABC')
]
values=[0,0,1]
df['NewCol'] = np.select(Conditions,values)

print(df)
```

This is the error I'm getting:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'bool' object is not callable
File "C:\Users\Johnr50\Documents\repos\SLHRoutine\testTFLkup.py", line 19, in 
(df['Shipped T/F?'].bool==True and df['Hold T/F?'].bool==True)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

I have tried the following solutions:
https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-valueerror-truth-value-series-ambiguous-use-empty-bool-item-any-or-all/
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-add-column-pandas-dataframe-based-on-if-else-condition/
And several others form StackOverflow which I can no longer find since I am posting this question.
[Update a df column based on three other columns values using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681452/update-a-df-column-based-on-three-other-columns-values-using-a-function)
[Create New True/False Pandas Dataframe Column based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543702/create-new-true-false-pandas-dataframe-column-based-on-conditions)

Comment: `(df['Shipped T/F?'] & df['Hold T/F?']),`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `Conditions`:

```
Conditions = [
    df['Category'] != 'ABC',
    df['Shipped T/F?'] & df['Hold T/F?'],  # <- HERE
    df['Category'] == 'ABC'
]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    ID Category  Shipped T/F?  Hold T/F?  NewCol
0  123      ABC         False      False       1
1  456      ABC         False       True       1
2  789      ABC          True      False       1
3  234      ABC          True       True       0
4  567      DEF         False      False       0
5  678      DEF         False       True       0
6  135      DEF          True      False       0
7  246      DEF          True       True       0
8  369      KGH          True       True       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I did not expect it the T/F comparison to so closely mirror the way Excel works.